# Error on querying element using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

This is a small section of a XML file I have.(see below).

I'm able to read what I need, like I can get the **type** and **message** etc. however in one of the **PreflightResultEntry** section there is a set of elements called Var I need the "`<Var name="NumPages">8</Var>`"

```
 --     
 <PreflightResultEntry type="GeneralDocInfo">
    <PreflightResultEntryMessage xml:lang="en-US">
        <Message>457834a.pdf </Message>
        <StringContext>
            <BaseString>%FileInfo%</BaseString>
            <Const name="Category">GeneralDocInfo</Const>
            <Const name="ActionID">-1</Const>
            <Instance>
                <Var name="FileInfo">
                    <Var name="DIPath">/V/PitStop/Testing/Mike/Processed Docs on Success/457834a.pdf</Var>
                    <Var name="CreationDate">D:20120724153648-05'00'</Var>
                    <Var name="ModDate">D:20120725134534-04'00'</Var>
                    <Var name="Producer">Adobe PDF Library 10.0</Var>
                    <Var name="Creator">Acrobat PDFMaker 10.1 for Word</Var>
                    <Var name="Author">DOL Comments</Var>
                    <Var name="Title"/>
                    <Var name="Subject"/>
                    <Var name="Keywords"/>
                    <Var name="Trapped">1</Var>
                    <Var name="NumPages">8</Var>
                    <Var name="Major">1</Var>
                    <Var name="Minor">5</Var>
                    <Var name="WasRepairedOnOpen">0</Var>
                    <Var name="IsLinearized">0</Var>
                    <Var name="ContainsThumbnails">0</Var>
                    <Var name="LeftToRightReading">1</Var>
                    <Var name="ContainsJobTicket">0</Var>
                    <Var name="EncryptionType">1</Var>
                    <Var name="Permissions">-1</Var>
                    <Var name="PrinergyTraps">3</Var>
                </Var>
                <Location page="-1"/>
            </Instance>
        </StringContext>
    </PreflightResultEntryMessage>
</PreflightResultEntry>
      ---
```

here what I have got that works for Messages and types

```
  List<PitStopMessage> messages = XDocument.Load(file)
      .Descendants("PreflightResultEntryMessage")
      .Where(x => x.Parent != null )
      .Select(x => new PitStopMessage()
      {
          message = x.Element("Message").Value,
          type = x.Parent.Attribute("type").Value,
          xmllevel = x.Parent.Attribute("level") != null ? x.Parent.Attribute("level").Value : String.Empty,
          link = 0
      }).ToList();
```

I need a new query to the elements var only if it exits in the parent element **PreflightResultEntry**

here what I have so far but its giving me a error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  which is telling what I'm looking for (elements) don't exist.

```
 List<PitStopPages> messages = XDocument.Load(file)
     .Descendants("PreflightResultEntryMessage")
     .Where(x => x.Parent != null && x.Parent.Attribute("type").Value == "GeneralDocInfo" && x.Parent.Element("Var").Value == "NumPages")
     .Select(x => new PitStopPages()
     {
         Pages = x.Parent.Attribute("name").Value
     }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you logically read through your query, you might spot the mistake.

Your query is trying to find:

- An element called `PreflightResultEntryMessage`
- Where its parent has a `type` attribute of `GeneralDocInfo`
- Where its parent element's first child named `Var` has the value `NumPages`
- Get the parent element's `name` attribute value

The issue is the last two parts.  `Parent` in all your cases is the `PreflightResultEntry` element. `PreflightResultEntry` does not have any child `Var` element, no `Var` elements have the *value* `NumPages`, and `PreflightResultEntry` has no `name` attribute.  Any one of these would cause a null reference exception (the exception you're seeing).

It's probably best to approach this from the top down rather than finding an element and then looking back up to its parent.  So:

- Find an element called `PreflightResultEntry` with a `type` attribute of `GeneralDocInfo`
- Get a descendant `Var` element has a `name` attribute of `NumPages`

So:

```
var numPages = (int)XDocument.Load(file)
        .Descendants("PreflightResultEntry")
        .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("type") == "GeneralDocInfo")
        .Descendants("Var")
        .Single(x => (string) x.Attribute("name") == "NumPages");
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ytmKIu) for a working demo.

Comment: thank you but the XML doc I supplied is only a snippet of the hold document. When I applied the code to the whole XML document document I get the following error: "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1." . some elements don't have all the elements as some of the other. so might have the element var and some may not. I think that's why I'm having the error.

Comment: okay I found the issue there is a DTD at the top of the document once I removed that it worked, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) to select the node you want. You can use the method [XPathSelectElements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342176(v=vs.90).aspx) and pass in your `XPath`. If you need to select only one node, you can use [XPathSelectElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351355(v=vs.110).aspx) (without 's') instead.

In your situation, I think the `XPath` should be: `/PreflightResultEntry//Var[@name='NumPages']`

You can test the `XPath` [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html).

Comment: this works on the the snippet I have posted but on the full xml file it don't work. the section PreflightResultEntry repeats but the Var does not. Not sure if that the issue or not. but that you.

Comment: You can check the output of the method. If the `Var` doesn't exist, it will return an empty list or `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Let me expand on what @AnhTriet suggested,

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();

xml.LoadXml(str);  // suppose that str string contains your xml

var xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/PreflightResultEntry//Var[@name='NumPages']");

foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(xn.InnerText); //this should print the 8
}
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cslOuy)

To be able to use the `XPathSelectElement` method you need to load first the xml using the `XDocument` class

So, it would be something like this:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(file);

XmlNode node = xml.XPathSelectElement("/PreflightResultEntry//Var[@name='NumPages']");

Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
```